# Missing data for time-series forecasting/classification

Tags: time-series, data-cleaning, missing-data

I want to train a model to predict some customer behavior. I have two types of data that I have to deal with. My measurements are daily.

The first type is regular measurements without any missing data, for any given day and customer, I have some value.

The second type depends on the interaction of the customer with the platform. If the customer did some specific action there will be available data and otherwise, there won't be. These kinds of interactions are rare and I have available data only on 5% of my daily measurements per customer.

I am in doubt about how I should handle these data, I wonder if it even makes sense to consider my second type of data as time-series data.
I have some ideas on how to treat them:

- I could do a cumulative count of events, so for each day, I would get how many interactions occurred until that day.
- I could aggregate the data in a larger time window, for example on a monthly basis, and output the result of the aggregation for the past month to the daily measurement.

Can anyone recommend some ways to treat the second type of data?